# Failed to dockerize my django app with elasticsearch

Tags: python, django, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I was working with django and elasticsearch in the same app and everything was working good until I decided to dockerize the whole app as It when I run `docker exec -it 4b93cbdacf84 python manage.py search_index --rebuild` it give me a response: `elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f9b532c8940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f9b532c8940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)`

docker-compose.yaml:

```
services:


  db:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: db
    # networks:
    #           - djangonetwork
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
  es:
    image: elasticsearch:7.9.1
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
      - elastic
    volumes:
      - ./data/elastic:/var/lib/elasticsearch/data

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    #   - /tmp/app/mysqld:/run/mysqld
    depends_on:
      - db
      - es
    networks:
      - elastic


  thesearchable:
      build: ./thesearchable
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
      volumes:
        - ./frontend:/frontend

volumes:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

documents.py

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document, fields, Index
from django_elasticsearch_dsl.registries import registry
from django.conf import settings
from .models import *
from elasticsearch_dsl import analyzer, tokenizer


autocomplete_analyzer = analyzer('autocomplete_analyzer',
            tokenizer=tokenizer('trigram', 'ngram', min_gram=1, max_gram=20),
            filter=['lowercase']
        )

entry_index=Index('entries')
# See Elasticsearch Indices API reference for available settings
# entry_index.settings(
#     number_of_shards=1,
#     number_of_replicas=0
# )

# @entry_index.document
@registry.register_document
class EntryDocument(Document):
    id = fields.IntegerField(attr='id')
    title = fields.TextField(
        attr='title',
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer=autocomplete_analyzer),
            'suggest': fields.CompletionField(),
            'key': fields.KeywordField(),
           
            
        }
    )
    body = fields.TextField(
        attr='body',
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer=autocomplete_analyzer),
            'suggest': fields.CompletionField(),
           
        }
    )

    entryauthor = fields.NestedField(
        attr='entryauthor',
        properties = {
        'id': fields.IntegerField(),
        'name': fields.TextField(
         attr='name',
        fields={
                'raw': fields.TextField(),
                'key': fields.KeywordField(),
               
                }
        ) },   )
    

    entryOrigin = fields.ObjectField(
        attr = 'entryOrigin',
        properties={
        'id': fields.IntegerField(),
        'country': fields.TextField(
        attr='country',
        fields={
                'raw': fields.KeywordField(),
               
                }
        )
        }
    )

    entryCategory = fields.ObjectField(
        attr='entryCategory',
        properties = {
        'id': fields.IntegerField(),
        'thecategory':  fields.TextField(
            attr='thecategory',
            fields={
        'key': fields.KeywordField(),
        'raw': fields.TextField()
            }
        ),

       
       
        
        }
    )

    entryClassification = fields.ObjectField(
        attr='entryClassification',
        properties = {
        'theclass':  fields.TextField(
        attr='theclass',
        fields={
        'key': fields.KeywordField(),
       
        }
        ),
        
        }
    )

    
    entryCover = fields.FileField(attr='entryCover')
    entryPubDate= fields.DateField(attr='entryPubDate')
    bibiliography = fields.TextField(
        attr='bibilography',
        fields = {
        'bibilography': fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword')
        }
    )
    favouriteusers = fields.ObjectField(
        attr='favouriteusers',
        properties = {
        'id':  fields.IntegerField(),
        
        }
    )
    viewsCounts = fields.IntegerField(attr='viewsCounts')

    class Index:
        name = 'entries'
        settings = {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 0,
            'max_ngram_diff': 20 
        }


    class Django:
        model = entry
        fields= []
```

settings.py:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': os.getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_DSL_HOSTS", 'localhost:9200')
    },
}

ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX_NAMES = {
    'entries.entry': 'entry',
}
```

This is a screenshot of the whole response:
[image]

The elastic search container works well on `localhost:9200` but the problem is in the connection between django container and elasticsearch container so how can I solve this?